# Combining ordinal scales to produce a single axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a bar chart, which consists of grouped data. Each group has its own ordinal scale, using `rangeBands` to position the bars:

[image: chart with two ordinal scales]

Using two scales allows me to adjust the spacing between the bars in each group, as well as the space between the groups.

If I pass one of the scales to `d3.svg.axis`, the tics are perfectly positioned in the centre of each pair of bars but obviously the range only covers one group.

How can I produce an axis that covers the full X range with the tics in the correct places?

I have tried to combine the values from `scale.range()` of each ordinal scale but if I do this, the axis doesn't reach either end of the chart.

---

#### Simplified example

I would like to create a single axis from the two scales in the following code.

```js
const scale1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([20, 180], 0.1)
  .domain(["one", "two"]);

const scale2 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([180, 420], 0.1)
  .domain(["three", "four", "five"]);

d3.select(".one").call(d3.svg.axis().scale(scale1));
d3.select(".two").call(d3.svg.axis().scale(scale2));
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.one {
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
}
.two {
  transform: translate(0, 30px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <svg width="440" height="100">
    <g class="axis one"></g>
    <g class="axis two"></g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not able to help you without seeing any code, but this is my 2 cents: you can call 2 different x axis.

Comment: @Gerardo I have added a simplified example to my question. If possible, I would rather not render multiple X axes.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I managed to combine the two ordinal scales.

- Each tick needs to be offset by half the width of each bar, i.e. `rangeBand() / 2`.
- In order to make the axis reach either end of the scale, extra points need adding to either end of the range, with corresponding `null` values added to the domain.

```js
const [rangeStart, rangeEnd] = [20, 420];

const scale1 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([rangeStart, 180], 0.1)
  .domain(["one", "two"]);

const scale2 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([180, rangeEnd], 0.1)
  .domain(["three", "four", "five"]);

const combined = [scale1, scale2].reduce((prev, curr) => {
  const offset = curr.rangeBand() / 2;
  return {
    range: [...prev.range, ...curr.range().map(x => x + offset)],
    domain: [...prev.domain, ...curr.domain()]
  };
}, {
  range: [],
  domain: []
});

const scaleFull = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range([rangeStart, ...combined.range, rangeEnd])
  .domain([null, ...combined.domain, null]);

d3.select(".one").call(d3.svg.axis().scale(scale1));
d3.select(".two").call(d3.svg.axis().scale(scale2));
d3.select(".full").call(d3.svg.axis().scale(scaleFull));
```

```css
.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.one {
  transform: translate(0, 10px);
}
.two {
  transform: translate(0, 30px);
}
.full {
  transform: translate(0, 60px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>

<div>
  <svg width="440" height="100">
    <g class="axis one"></g>
    <g class="axis two"></g>
    <g class="axis full"></g>
  </svg>
</div>
```